# React + Vite + VitePWA plugin workbox configurations

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite, workbox, vite-plugin-pwa

I'm trying to cache some url in order to have my app working offline.

I'm using vite `5.0.5` vite-plugin-pwa `0.17.3`

and here is my vite.config.js

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import postcssNested from 'postcss-nested';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: true, //@todo false in prod
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    VitePWA({
      strategies: 'generateSW',
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      mode: 'development',
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,jsx,css,html,png,svg,woff2,json}'],
        runtimeCaching: [
          {
            urlPattern: /\/api\//,
            handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
            method: 'GET',
            options: {
              cacheName: 'api-cache',
              cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      manifest: {
        name: 'AppName',
        short_name: 'AppName',
        description: 'App description',
        theme_color: '#ffffff',
        icons: [
          {
            src: '/manifestIcons/maskable_icon_x1024.png',
            sizes: '1024x1024',
            type: 'image/png',
            purpose: 'any maskable',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [postcssNested],
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    host: true,
  },
});
```

But it seems that it doesn't work, there's only 1 entry in the cache :
[image]

Why my "api-cache" doesn't show ?

I DO have a status 200 request including `/api/` :

[image]

And I can see this in the sw.js :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same problem it has been solved [HERE](https://github.com/vite-pwa/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/626)

The problem was that with "only" `urlPattern: /regexp/` workbox won't cache CORS calls if the `regexp` pattern doesn't match your WHOLE url !

Then you'll have to either

- Change your regexp to match the whole URL
- Use the callback form like this :

`urlPattern: ({ url, sameOrigin }) => sameOrigin && url.pathname.match(/^\/api\//),`